# Is there a list/catalog of types of regression to choose from?

Tags: regression, modeling

In my practice, I often find out that after the basic assumptions for linear regression are not met, I have to discover a new type of regression I should use. For example, in the past, I came across the need for Non-negative binomial regression and Lagged dependent variable models. However, in all cases I found out about these models in a rather ad-hoc manner, and I get the feeling that they might even not be the most appropriate models.

Thus my question is: given I have a clear question, I know the types and distribution of data involved in my model, is there a catalog/procedure/site/something alike where I should start to look for the most appropriate regression model to use?